# Prevent page break between thead and tbody when printing

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-print

I have some dynamic content, and when printing I found browsers will insert a page break between a tables `<thead>` and the following `<tbody>`, resulting in things like this screenshot depending on the preceding dynamic content.

I want it to move the table/header to the next page in this case so I don't have a header by itself.

`break-after: avoid` looks like it should be the CSS rule for this, I tried it on combinations of the `thead`, the contained `tr`, and the `th`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Mostly tried on Chrome, I got similar results in Firefox, I would like this to work in all major browsers if possible.

In many cases tables will fit the current page fine, so I don't want to start every table on a new page. They might also be longer than one entire page, and need to be able to break somewhere between rows.

[image: Chrome print to PDF]

```css
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      thead {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      thead tr {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      thead tr th {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      td, th {
        border: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
        padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
      }
      td {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      td p:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
      td p:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid red; width: 200px; height: 240mm">
  <p>Consume Space</p>
  <p>Required height for effect is browser dependent</p>
  <button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
 </div>
<table>
  <thead><tr><th><div>Name</div></th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have you try `@media print {};` ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see media print resolve your problem

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      thead {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      thead tr {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      thead tr th {
        break-after: avoid; /* No effect */
      }
      td, th {
        border: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
        padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
      }
      td {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      td p:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
      td p:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
@media print {
  table {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid red; width: 200px; height: 240mm">
  <p>Consume Space</p>
  <p>Required height for effect is browser dependent</p>
  <button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
 </div>
<table>
  <thead><tr><th><div>Name</div></th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>X</td><td>Y</td><td><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p><p>Z</p></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can play with that for desidered result.

Comment: Adding `page-break-inside: avoid` will move the problem given "might also be longer than one entire page". Consider https://jsfiddle.net/k0bej5vx/ and it leaves practically one text line on a page.

`@media print` here seems to have no effect, the rule applies anyway, but "screen" doesn't have "pages" so it doesn't hurt either way I think.